# Searching for an entry in a MYSQL table

Tags: php

I have a MYSQL table called members with 2 columns as follows:

```
username
john
sam

colleges_i_like
"yale ", "stanford", "columbia"
"princeton", "cornell"
```

I would like to create a PHP query that allows me to select users who like a certain college ($college).

I wrote this code but it is not working (I am new to PHP, this is the first line of code I am writing).  Can you please help me correct it?

```
$college='yale';
$result = "SELECT * FROM members where $college IN 'colleges_i_like'";
```

Comment: is `colleges_i_like` a `ENUM` type of those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try someting like :

```
$college='yale';
$result = "SELECT * FROM members where 'colleges_i_like' LIKE '%".$college."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your use at least `PHP MySQLi` and not deprecated `MySQL` extension.

Second, you should use WHERE statement if you'd like to match something to something else. Below is my code, written for MySQLi.

Your connection when using MySQLi:

```
$myDB = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
```

You have to write something like this:

```
// Prepare you QUERY to be exeuted, note the questuion mark at the end of
//  of the query, this should be replaced with a real value 
$stmt = $myDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE colleges_i_like = ?");

// In this statement we replace the ? with real variable. "s" means string and
// I assume your colleges_i_like is string.
$stmt->bind_params("s", $myCollege);

// execute your query
$stmt->execute();

// get the result (PHP 5.4 > )
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// iterating over the results
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   echo "Username is: " . $row["username"] . "<br />";
}
```

Now if you have several colleges in your field, you query should be like this:

```
$stmt = $myDB->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM myTable WHERE colleges_i_like LIKE ?");
```

And then wrap your variable (which replaces ? in the bind_param()) with this:

```
$colleges = "%"."CollegeName"."%";
```

I like to add that, if your PHP version is below 5.4, for fetching the results, you should follow this:

```
$results = array();

// Instead of star, we use certain fields so that our job in fetching them gets easier
$stmt = $myDB->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM myTable WHERE colleges_i_like = ?");

// bind params (no change)
$stmt->bind_params("s", $myCollege);

// execute your query (no change)
$stmt->execute();

// we binds the results to certain variables. Define the variable first, so to avoid
// undefined warning/notice
$stmt->bind_result($results['id'], $results['username']);

// fetching the results
while($stmt->fetch())
{
   echo "Id is: " . $row["id"] . "<br />";
   echo "Username is: " . $row["username"] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two columns are in the same table and the data in "college_i_like" is in separate rows you could do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE college_i_like LIKE '%yale%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```